# Facebook access_token for stranger account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there a way to get an `access_token` to get a stranger account photos, albums and friends?
As i can see you can get (with the right `access_token`) all the information belonging to you and your friends using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[User_ID]/friends?access_token=[A_T]
https://graph.facebook.com/[User_ID]/albums?access_token=[A_T]
https://graph.facebook.com/[User_ID]/photos?access_token=[A_T]
```

what about the friends of your friends and perfectly stranger? Are they reachable in such a way?

I ask this because using the normal browser i can get the public photos of unfriend account, so i thought that can be a way to get that information through the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, the facebook privacy is to tight to do such a thing.